# Windows XP wont copy files to network location or USB

Tags: networking, windows-xp, usb

My windows XP system can see all the network drives that i have mapped on it and it can also browse through all the files and folders created within them.

However I can't transfer any files to the mapped network drives.

I have checked all the permissions out and have ensured that the XP machine has full access to everything (that its allowed to have). I have also tried to put these files onto a USB stick to transfer manually but it wont even put them onto the external device.

Anyone have any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: You say "that it's allowed to have".  Have you checked for a security policy? Many corporate PCs nowadays won't allow a copy to removable media for security reasons.  Although that does sound excessive for mapped network drives!

Comment: this is the only machine in a group of around 6 that doesn't allow the transfer. They are all in the same work group (not allowed to be on a domain because they are networked to CNC machines)

Answer (score 0):

You may have sharing permissions given correctly but you may be missing the NTFS permissions in the security tab.

Note: for windows home, you will have to manually enable the security tab, it does not show by default. XP Pro has it available by default.

Check this [guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456988.aspx) to see how both type of settings look like.

Comment: I have checked this this morning and the NTFS permissions are set as they should be. Good idea though, i hadn't thought to check this.

Comment: Also try to replace owner on subcontainers and objects (Security-->Advanced-->Change). Also make sure the Everyone permission is set (R,W). This may deny correct permissions even for admin groups otherwise. It's safe to do since the actual permission is controlled via NTFS/Security Tab.

Comment: I've done that but still no good. It doesn't come up with any error messages which is why I'm thinking that this inst an issue with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed this.
Wile trying to fix the issue with the USB transfer i updated the USB drivers and the transfer now works.

This also somehow fixed the network issue (although i have no idea how)